# Git refuses to remove a branch

Tags: git, github

I have a single branch on this GitHub repository (which is not master) and now I'm trying to rename it and for some reason I am getting this error:

```
git push origin :OldName
To git@github.com:user/gitRepo.git
 ! [remote rejected] OldName (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/OldName)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user/gitRepo.git'
```

Is this because I don't have any master branch? Here's my `git branch -a`:

```
OldName
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/OldName
remotes/origin/OldName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output from `git branch -a` be accurate, then it appears you only have a single branch `OldName`, and single corresponding branch by the same name on GitHub.  It doesn't make much sense for you to be deleting the only branch in the repository, because then there would be no content, nothing, in that repository (except for maybe the reflog, if that still exists).

Specifically, the error is likely being caused for a slightly different reason.  Since the `OldName` branch is the only branch in GitHub, is also most likely the *default* branch for your repository.  GitHub will not allow you to delete the default branch, because then it means that someone browsing your repo might not be able to see content.

To get around this problem, you can create a branch with the name you want, and do the deletions from there:

**Locally**

```
git checkout -b NewName  # create a dummy branch from OldName
git push origin NewName
```

**On GitHub**

Change the default branch to `NewName`

**Locally (again):**

```
git push origin :OldName
```

Comment: For this to work, you also need to change the default branch in the settings of the project in Github, otherwise, you get the same error when trying to delete the old branch.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a [git] restriction, but [github] doing an extra layer of sanity protection for you. Change the [default branch] in the GitHub project of yours, and then try again.

Sample URL (change **[user]** and **[project]**) for the settings page on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/[user]/[project]/settings/branches
                   ^      ^
                   change these placeholders
```

To reiterate:

1. Tweak the above URL to reach the `/settings/branches` page of your own project.
2. Do any necessary change(s) to effectively "unprotect" the branch in question.
3. Retry the "push to delete" operation again and it should work.

Comment: @kboul That's not a link to a real resource. You need to substitute [user] and [project] with your own username and your own project name.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I did not notice [user], just clicked to check the link

Comment: I see 404 error, it means that I am not admin or not allowed to see this url?

Answer (score 0):

I has to move the default branch on github repository before deleting that from remote git repository. After removing that branch from default branch I ran the command (again):
git push origin --delete [Branch Name] --force

And issue resolved.